# TSQL - Non-system tables in an SQL Server 2000 database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to retrieve the names of Non-system -tables in a database from SQL Server 2000 by a T-SQL query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from sysobjects
where xtype = 'U'
```

The system tables have an object_type of "S" - so that should give you just your user tables.

See the [sysobjects documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260447%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for details on the possible object types.

```
Object type. Can be one of these object types:

C = CHECK constraint
D = Default or DEFAULT constraint
F = FOREIGN KEY constraint
L = Log
FN = Scalar function
IF = Inlined table-function
P = Stored procedure
PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint (type is K)
RF = Replication filter stored procedure
S = System table
TF = Table function
TR = Trigger
U = User table
UQ = UNIQUE constraint (type is K)
V = View
X = Extended stored procedure
```

Marc

Comment: I tried that query but the results still show tables from System Tables (I'm using Sql Server 2012)

Comment: @Zain: in SQL Server 2012, I'd use `select * from sys.tables where is_ms_shipped = 0`

Comment: Didn't work. Don't know what I'm doing something wrong here. I've got a tiny DB I just recently created and it has dbo.sysdiagrams under the System Tables folder.  The only difference I see between it and the other tables in sys.tables is that it has lob_data_space_id set to 1. Ring any bells?

Comment: @Zain: *didn't work* - ***HOW*** did it not work? No results? Error? Or what is it showing that you didn't expect to see?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it outputted all the tables, including the system table dbo.sysdiagrams. I expect it to not show the dbo.sysdiagrams table (btw, thanks for these super fast responses. I really appreciate it)

Comment: @Zain: well, `sysdiagrams` is **NOT** a strict system table! You will see `sysdiagrams` as a "normal" user table - but that's a design decision the SQL Server team made - you cannot help that..... `sysdiagrams` has `is_ms_shipped = 0` - so it **will show up** as a normal user table!

Comment: Ahh, gotcha, that sucks, but thanks for helping me figure this out

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sysobjects table

```
-- FOR TABLES
SELECT * 
FROM sysobjects o
WHERE type = 'U'

-- FOR VIEWS
SELECT * 
FROM sysobjects o
WHERE type = 'V'

-- FOR STORED PROCEDURES
SELECT * 
FROM sysobjects o
WHERE type = 'P'
```

You can also use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` in SQL Server 2000 onwards

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```